# Conflict between listings and gb4e?

Tags: listings, incompatibility, gb4e

this code doesn't compile for me. Could it be a bug or is something wrong with my LaTex installation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll Isso é um exemplo.\\
This is an example\\
\trans `This is an example.'
\end{exe}
\begin{lstlisting}
source code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

My goal: have glossed examples AND indented source code (the verbatim environment did not indent the code).

Comment: Because `gb4e` messes with catcodes, it's best to load it last or almost last in your list of packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

load it the other way round:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{gb4e}
```

but remember that listings cannot handle UTF-8 characters when using `pdflatex`

Comment: Thank you both (@Herbert and @AllanMunn), it works now :) @Herbert, by **UTF-8 characters**, you mean the non-English characters (é, ã, ...)? But these do come out for me within listings and I am indeed using **pdflatex**. Probably because I have other packages loaded such as **[brazilian,english]{babel}**, **[latin1]{inputenc}**, **[T1]{fontenc}**?